# JS function .hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a objects in .less, and i have created a few buttons in a php file, when the button is clicked in the php file I want some of the objects to hide.  Here is my php code

```
 <label for="select-pattern">Select</label>
          <select name="" id="select" data-native-menu="false">
            <option data-placeholder="true">Select</option>
            <option name="asdf" value="pat">Select this</option>
            <option name="fdas" value="tap">select now</option>
    <select>
```

here is my JS code,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#asdf").click(function(event){
     //Your actions here
       $('#object1, #object2').hide();

   });
 });
```

the less file is where i created the objects, here is the code for that

```
 #object1, #object2 {
    width: 46px;
    height: 23px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
```

Why isn't the hide function not working? is their an error in the code?

Comment: Where is your button in code???? only dropdown with that name is there

Comment: so will the drop down, won't work?

Comment: you need to use change event and that will be  better than click

Comment: something like this " '#asdf'.onchange=function(){('#object1, #object2').hide()};"

Answer (score 0):

your are having HTML not PHP.
I don't believe the click event is valid on options.
You have to make a button,and set asfd as id not the name of the element.

```
<input type="button" id="asdf" value="Hide objects">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (Assuming the object1 and object2 refers to html elements in your DOM).

You need a change event on the select and check its value. If match, hide the object1 , object2.

```
    <label for="select-pattern">Select</label>
              <select name="" id="select" data-native-menu="false">
                <option data-placeholder="true">Select</option>
                <option name="asdf" value="pat">Select this</option>
                <option name="fdas" value="tap">select now</option>
        <select>
            <div id="object1">Object 1</div>
            <br>
                <br>
                <div id="object2">Object 2</div>
$().ready(function()
{
$("select").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == "pat")
       $('#object1, #object2').hide();
    else
        $('#object1, #object2').show();

   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9tvmac08/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on("change", function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        $(".objects #"+id).toggle();
    });
});
```

Or, according to your code:

```
$("#object1, #object2").toggle();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8mxqvLwb/

If you want to bind some event to option element in select, you have to bind it to select element.